# Perspective Projection Matrix transforms like Orthogonal

Tags: c#, math, matrix

Suppose I have a point which is not in (0, 0, 0) and a perspective camera which is looking at (0, 0, 0).
To my understanding, if I move the perspective camera along the z axis, the point on the screen should move as well. The further the camera is, the closer the point should be towards (0, 0) in screen coordinates.

In my C# program, the camera movement does not affect screen coordinates (x, y) at all. It only changes the z coordinate just like an orthogonal camera. Here is the minimal example:

```
        Vector3 v = new Vector3(3.0f);
        // Move camera z to  -10 from the center
        Matrix4x4 viewMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        Matrix4x4 projectionMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 3.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        Vector3 v1 = Vector3.Transform(v, viewMatrix * projectionMatrix);
        Console.WriteLine(v1); //<-5.1961527, 5.1961527, 12.912912>
        // Move camera z to -1 from the center
        viewMatrix = Matrix4x4.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        Vector3 v2 = Vector3.Transform(v, viewMatrix * projectionMatrix);
        Console.WriteLine(v2); //<-5.1961527, 5.1961527, 3.903904>
```

What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Maybe the W of projected coord is not 1. `Vector4.Transform()` and divide XYZ by the W.

Comment: That's it. For some reason I thought that Vector3.Transform was a bit smarter. This should be an answer.

Comment: I posted an answer with more informations. If you solved the issue, please mark the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the W of projected coord is not 1.

In vertex shaders, the returned W means point or vector. If 1, it is point. But for some reason, the vertex shaders automately divide XYZ by W. Therefore, the vertex shader need not to set W as 1 explicitly and almost of 3D math libraries return W as divisor instead of 1.

If you want to get proper projected coord, manually divide. `Vector4.Transform()` and divide XYZ by the W.